# validate the referrer before redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp-2.0

I need to validate that the referrer URL still exists before redirecting to it. In my app I need to delete some records then redirect the user to the page he came from. But due to the pagination, After deleting the last record in a page, the user is redirected to non-exist page.

I tried:`$headers = @get_headers($this->referer());`
then check if `$headers[0]` doesn't contain `404`. The problem is that after deleting the last record, I get the same HTTP response `302` when I try `get_headers` function

Answer (score 0):

Is the user redirected to a realy non-existing page? Or does the page still exist but with no records? Cause that's a different situation.

In the first situation your app must return a 404. You should build it in.

In the second situation, you can also build in that the page returns 404 when there are no records left. Or, another way of fixing this: redirects to user to the page, check whether or not there are records left on the page. If not... do an extra redirect.

I hope that helps u on your way...